# How to generate an ireport according user input in netbean gui

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, jasper-reports, ireport

```
CREATE TABLE Account(
    account_no int,
    balance real,
    type_code int,
    branch_no int,
    Bcode int,
    customer_no int,

    CONSTRAINT account_pk PRIMARY KEY (account_no),

);
```

I want to generate a Jasper Report when user gives the `type_code(account type code)` or `branch_no` as GUI inputs, then  the ireport should display all the account details of above account table.

I have no idea how to do this. can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you didn't specify the kind of application you want to create, so i'm being a bit general on my response. Also you didn't mention if you've already managed to build your first report (i mean, without taking any user input). So, below i'm showing the needed part for generating a JasperReport:

```
public void generateReport(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws FileNotFoundException {

JRBeanCollectionDataSource ds = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(PopulateBean.createBeanCollection());
Map parameters = new HashMap();
 
try {
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("Source path to template.jrxml"));
    OutputStream os=new FileOutputStream(new File("Resulting report.pdf"));
     
    JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(is);
    JasperReport jasperReport =
        JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);

    JasperPrint jasperPrint =
        JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, ds);

    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, os);
} catch (JRException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

This code should be integrated into your application. The part you are asking for is:

```
Map parameters = new HashMap();
```

You have just to put the input inserted by the user into this map. Example, if you have a JSF page, then you can take the value of it's UI component and store in this map

```
parameters.put("type_code", getTypeCodeUIComponent().getValue());
```

You'll see on the code above that this map is passed to the report:

```
JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, ds);
```

The only thing that remains is to edit your report query, in iReport. First you create a parameter with the exact same name as that inserted into the map (in this example "type_code". Note, it's case sensitive). Second, you should use a WHERE clause where you filter the type column based on this parameter, see below:
[image: passing parameters]
And here you go some tutorials:[1](http://www.ramkitech.com/2011/11/jsf-jpa-jasperreports-ireport.html) and [2](http://www.gebs.ro/blog/oracle/jasper-reports-in-adf/)

Hope these helps!

Comment: I can generate reports without gui inputs.
and my GUI snapshot is attached below link
<a href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9tyULY_FLygalZXdmRtY29NY3c/edit?usp=sharing">my link</a>

and your code generate an error like below.
<a href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9tyULY_FLygdXFLR2xmT0tRMFE/edit?usp=sharing">error page link<a>

I am beginner to java programming. thank you for your great explanation

Comment: PopulateBean is a class implemented in the second tutorial i've linked above. And createBeanCollection() is a static method. Of course you don't have such a class or method. So you can replace the whole "PopulateBean.createBeanCollection()" with another data source (such as a list). Or you can remove the whole line:  "JRBeanCollectionDataSource ds = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(PopulateBean.createBeanCollection());
"  and set null instead of ds in JasperFillManager

Comment: ok I will follow the tutorial and if anything goes wrong I will contact you. 
thank you.