# JasperReport in Netbeans + java

Tags: database, jdbc, netbeans, derby

I'm able to call my report via my program in Netbeans. Right now, when I call my report, it displays all the data from the database with 6 or more pages. My program goes like the user would choose a date and JTable will display the data (entered beforehand and saved in database) associated with that date. My question is how do I show the report to display only the specific data chosen by the user from database (date-wise)? I thought at first that changing the SQL statement to fetch the specific date from the database would do the trick, but it did not and still shows the whole database in the report.

Comment: A SQL `select` statement uses the `where` clause to filter the result set to contain only the desired records. It sounds like you need a `where` clause that contains a date range of some sort. Try searching the net for some of those keywords for more examples, etc.

Comment: +1 Thanks! Specifically, I followed this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22345275/how-to-generate-an-ireport-according-user-input-in-netbean-gui